# Makefile.PL - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, perl, makefile, perforce

I am trying to build the Perforce Perl API as per [this](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4perlnotess.txt) link. However, when I issue the command **perl Makefile.PL**, I get the error "Makefile.PL - No such file or directory".

Perl is installed in my Linux machine. When I issue the command **perl -v** , the following is displayed:

*This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i386-linux-thread-multi
Copyright 1987-2006, Larry Wall*

Can someone please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: It says: "Makefile.PL - No such file or directory". Have you checked if this file is actually present in the current directory?

Comment: Makefile.PL is not present in the current directory. Apologies for the dumb question - where can I get the Makefile.PL?

Comment: That link seems to assume that you have already downloaded some Perl module separately from the C++ api modules. Is that true?  If so, what Perl module did you download?

Comment: which Perforce package did you download? You need to make sure you download the actual p4perl package. Try ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r11.1/bin.tools/p4perl.tgz

Comment: Thanks Bill and Steven. I was not having the right p4perl module when I was trying the Makefile command. I have now downloaded the p4perl API and all is well!

Comment: @stevenl, Why don't you make your reply into a proper answer so this question can be marked as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not having the right p4perl module when I was trying the Makefile command. I have now downloaded the p4perl API and able to execute the Makefile command.